# how to load .dat file to hive or hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, apache-pig

how to load  .dat file to hive or cloudera or hdfs?

is it necessary to convert this format to structured format by using pig?

if it is yes can someone gives pig script to convert this to structure data?

My data looks like this when i open .dat file in notepad++

```
Americas¤AME  ¤ZONE¤ ¤¤¤Active¤
Asia-Pacific¤APA  ¤ZONE¤ ¤¤¤Active¤
Europe¤EUR  ¤ZONE¤ ¤¤¤Active¤
Middle East, India and Africa¤MAI  ¤ZONE¤ ¤¤¤Active¤
Unidentified¤999  ¤ZONE¤ ¤¤¤Active¤
Afghanistan¤AF   ¤COUNTRY¤ ¤MAI  ¤ZONE¤Active¤3
Albania¤AL   ¤COUNTRY¤ ¤EUR  ¤ZONE¤Active¤1
Algeria¤DZ   ¤COUNTRY¤ ¤MAI  ¤ZONE¤Active¤3
American Samoa¤AS   ¤COUNTRY¤ ¤APA  ¤ZONE¤Active¤3
Andorra¤AD   ¤COUNTRY¤ ¤EUR  ¤ZONE¤Active¤1
Angola¤AO   ¤COUNTRY¤ ¤MAI  ¤ZONE¤Active¤1
```

Comment: `.dat` does not indicate a format. Your data seems to be delimited. Please add to your post the results of `od -Anone -N50 -w50 -tx1a yourfile`

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to load the data in hdfs ?

`hadoop fs -put ./myfile.dat /home/hadoop/dir`

Now your file is in hdfs and you can use it in your code using the delimiter in your data.
Just checked the data with '¤'

```
   cat spch.dat | awk -F'¤' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'
```

> Americas AME   ZONE
>   Asia-Pacific APA   ZONE
>   Europe EUR   ZONE
>   Middle East, India and Africa MAI   ZONE

```
// Pig 
A = LOAD '/hadoop/dir/myfile.dat' usig PigStorage('¤') as (field1,filed2 ..);
// use the fields
```